# Execute referenced js after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, execute

I want to execute a script added dynamically to the page (via `innerHTML`) I found this:

[how to execute ajax output script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496014/how-to-execute-ajax-output-script)

Which is close, but no cigar. I'm getting one of these (along with other content) in my AJAX response:

```
<link rel=StyleSheet href="/my/css/file.css" type="text/css"/>
<h1>Some header</h1>
<div>Some text</div>
<ul><li>Some text</li><li>Some Text</li></ul>
<script src='my/js/file.js'></script>
```

And I'm attempting to eval it after it's appended to my container element (via `innerHTML`):

```
scripts = mycontainer.querySelectorAll('script');
for (k=0;k<scripts.length;k++){
    eval(scripts[k]);
}
```

But to no avail. Any ideas? **No** libraries, please! (Don't need fallbacks either, only most modern browsers).

CSS loads just fine. JS file exists and is correctly referenced.

Comment: Could you post your full script, including the ajax call and the script that interprets this call and returns your script list?

Comment: @freon No. Simply because there IS a library involved, but it's the in-house library that I have no control over. I can tell you, for sure, that I'm getting the correct response, the js file is correctly referenced, and the `<script>` tag is being added to the page no problem. My function for getting the script list is posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone comes up with a better way...

I'm going to end up using an AJAX call to get each script src, and eval the return. I'll post the relevant code here in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, I'll just make some assumptions.

scriptlist.php

```
<?php
   //get script list somehow.
   $script_list = array('my/js/file1.js', 'my/js/file2.js', 'my/js/file3.js');
   echo json_encode($script_list);
?>
```

page.html

```
function ajaxRequest(){
 var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
 if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
   try{
    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
   }
   catch(e){
    //suppress error
   }
  }
 }
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
 else
  return false
}

var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   var scripts = eval("("+mygetrequest.responseText+")") //retrieve result as an JavaScript object
   var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   for (k=0;k<scripts.length;k++){
      var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      newScript.src = scripts[k];
      headID.appendChild(newScript);
   }

  }
  else{
   alert("An error has occured making the request")
  }
 }
}

mygetrequest.open("GET", "scriptlist.php", true)
mygetrequest.send(null)
```

Ref. used.:

- [Get JSON from another (php) file using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149864/get-json-from-another-php-file-using-pure-javascript)
- [Howto Dynamically Insert Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS)

Comment: Not quite... I'm getting an HTML page response from the AJAX call, and there's a `<script>` tag somewhere in the HTML (possibly multiple script tags) that I want to execute after the HTML is added to the dom. Since the script tags are a reference, and don't actually contain the scripts (*NOT* `<script>alert('hi');</script>`), eval isn't working.

Comment: Well, I can't guess what is happening.

Comment: @RandyHall: `eval` is for JavaScript only, and can't execute HTML code. You'll have to *put* the HTML code in the page using `innerHTML` of an element (e.g.: a `DIV`). The web browser will interpret the HTML code and load any external script or style.

Comment: @Jay The external script I'm referencing isn't being pulled by the browser (Chrome). I'm watching the network, can see the HTML come through, can even see a css link that comes with the returned markup being pulled. But the JS is not even being requested by the browser, so this is confusing me. I would have assumed it would be smart enough to grab the JS as well...

Comment: @RandyHall: The data may have been filtered by a third-party browser extension, anti-virus, or security tools. Or may be there were some server changes you're unaware of. i.e.: API changes.

Comment: @Jay If I click the src in the element explorer, it finds it just fine. If I load just the HTML page separately, it loads up and executes just fine. All the JS files (there's a LOT) are coming from the same directory and it's all on my local server. But you're sure that a script tag is supposed to load and execute after being added using `innerHTML`? If so, I at least know which way to look now.

Comment: @RandyHall: It depend on where the container is located. If the contained isn't yet added into the web page (e.g.: *attached / put into* using `document.body.appendChild`), all external objects won't be loaded. They will be loaded until the container is put into the web page.

Comment: @Jay The container is a div on the page, and it already exists. The content is added to that div using innerHTML

Comment: @RandyHall: I can only think that the external script tag is within a HTML comment, but I can't be sure since there's not enoug information. Please update your question to add an example of the full HTML code that was retrieved from the server. Post it to *pastebin.com* if it's too large. Also try with different web browser please.