# How to make post.php to popup message using jquery UI when post data in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery to submit a form, which calls `another.php`, then I use jQuery-UI for a pop-up message, but it is not showing.

Without post, if I give the parameters as variables it will show the popup message.

This is the jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#divhide").hide();
  $('#info').submit(function() {
    $.post('another.php',$('#info').serialize(), function() {
      location.reload(true);
    });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

And this is the code in `another.php`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
     width: 200,
     hide: 'slide',
     position: 'top',
     show: 'slide',
     close: function(event, ui) {
       window.location.href = history.back();
    }
  });
});
</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Error">
  <p><?php echo "Error : Already  X has the value $X"; ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't return HTML/JS from an AJAX request. Instead return actual data in a serialised format, such as JSON or XML, and work with that in the promise of the `$.ajax()` call

Comment: I see no value here in the code in another.php being in a different **PHP** file. If you wanted to make it re-usable, put the contents of it in a **JavaScript** file, and wrap it in a function ( and before you ask, you could use JS to add/remove the `<div id="dialog"` from the DOM), include that in your main page and then just call the function when you want to show a dialog. AJAX is completely the wrong tool for the task of showing a popup. If another.php does actually also process the form data, then please keep it, but move the task of showing the popup into the "success" of your AJAX call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing Javascript in Ajax-called page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21375746/1843510)

Comment: See this answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/59918008/12232340

Comment: You should return data  from your post request and on `success` you can open the dialog. On `fail` do something else. That is the logical way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of AJAX is that you can send data to the server or get data from the server via HTTP without having to reload the entire page.

For example, if you're posting data to a PHP Script with:

```
$(function() {
  $("#divhide").hide();
  $('#info').submit(function() {
    $.post('another.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      $("#divhide").html(data).show();
    });
  return false;
});
```

Your script will post data to the PHP and get some result, as the `data` variable back. JavaScript can accept a lot of data types back, Text, HTML, JSON, and XML for example. So if you're expecting HTML back, you can just append it to an object.

For example, if `another.php` has the following code:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Error">
  <p><?php echo "Error : Already X has the value $X"; ?></p>
</div>
```

Then this will come back in `data` and using `.html()` we can append it to an element.